# How to search the encrypted data using like operator in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, sql-like

Data saved in the MYSQL tables in an encrypted way cannot be searched by like operator.
We have saved it using openssl_encrypt(), it is only working with the same value.

## Here is the code we are using to encrypt and decrypt the data.

```
$key = 'MY KEY';
$iv = '123456';
$plaintext = 'Text for encryption';
ENCRYPT CODE
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
return base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext);


DECRYPT CODE
$plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-128-CBC', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
return $plaintext;
```

Comment: seems like you would need to decrypt the data before searching which makes this an expensive operation. Mysql has built-in encryption functions available (`aes_encrypt/aes_decrypt`) which would make this process easier perhaps or scale up to [MySQL Enterprise Encryption](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html)

Comment: For example: nileshtest@gmail.com email saved in MYSQL DB as FDXCjkjHGH422GKJK by encryption. Now i want to search by keyword as nileshtest, so how can i do that?

Comment: This is not possible if you are using any sensible encryption because the encrypted data is essentially random and e.g. `nileshtest@gmail.com` will generate a completely different encrypted string than `nileshtest@hotmail.com` making it impossible to find similarities. You will need to decrypt all the data first and then search on them

Comment: You either need a transparent encryption (data is protected only at rest from direct access, not through sql queries - mysql offers it as enterprse encryption referenced in the 1st comnent) or your encryption must produce the same crypto text for the same charater all the time for a search like that to work. The first type of encryption must be built into the database, the 2nd type is unsafe in today's world.